# why self referencing table?

Tags: sql-server

In what scenarios a self referencing table is used?

Comment: Are you serious? This is your question? -1

Comment: @Ryk is right this is a weak question but if you are serious I dropped an answer below. Please consider elaborating on what you mean.

Comment: Hi,is there anything wrong in my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you want to represent a tree in a SQL table (mostly category tree).
You have structure like

```
Category (cat_id,cat_name,cat_parent_id).
```

Here `cat_parent_id` refers back to the same table.

This is just one example. You may find lot as you see new data models.

Answer (score 1):

Usually this is used when records of a table can have a parent-child relationship.

For instance if you had an employees table, you might have

```
employees
---------
id
first_name
last_name
boss_id
```

boss_id would be referring to another record in the employees table.

Answer (score 0):

Self referencing tables is where the table referenced itself, in, for example:

Heirarchical data

Typically the table has a foreign key to another of its feilds.